# Can a Safari popover access to the page url?

Tags: url, safari, popover

I'm building a Safari Extension, and I wanted to have a button on the main toolbar, which opens a popover.

But the problem is:
1) How to access to the current tab URL from the popover ?
2) How to load the popover only when I open it ?

Answer (score 0):

1) You can access to the current tab url from injected scripts (window.location.href), just send to injected script message, get url and send callback to popover.

2) You have to create popover dynamically on click toolbar button. Then assign popover to toolbar item. And show it

```
myPop = safari.extension.createPopover("myPopoverID", safari.extension.baseURI + "myFile.html", width, height);
myToolbarItem.popover=myPop;
myToolbarItem.showPopover();
```

After all actions with popover you must deallocate it.

Check visibility of popover, assign null to toolbar item and remove popover

```
if(myPop.visible == false){
   myToolbarItem.popover = null;
   safari.extension.removePopover(myPop.identifier);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question.

But I recently wanted to do this. You can access the tabs url from inside your popover.html  with:

```
var url= safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.url;
```